# Finding the nearest target in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can anyone help me? I don't know what's wrong but my script isn't working when I have more than 2 targets.

```
GameObject[] cores;
GameObject closest_core = null;
cores = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("bldg_core");

if (cores.Length != 1)
    for (int x = 0; x < cores.Length - 1; x++) 
    {
        if (distanceToPlayer (cores[x + 1]) < distanceToPlayer (cores[x]))
            closest_core = cores [x + 1];
    }
```

Comment: what exactly does "isn't working" mean? Why are you intializing the `closest_core` to be null? What happens if  `cores[0]` is actually the closest? It will remain null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing the current GameObject of the loop with the closest.

You should do something like:

```
GameObject[] cores;
GameObject closest_core = null;
float dist, minDist = 999999f;
cores = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("bldg_core");
for (int x = 0; x < cores.Length; x++) {
    dist = distanceToPlayer (cores [x]);
    if(dist < minDist){
        minDist = dist;
        closest_core = cores[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: dang you're right. I need some sleep O_O. Thanks Man

Comment: You could use Mathf.Infinity rather than 999999f

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the closest core as you loop through. At the moment you are only comparing the current object distance in the array to the next object distance.

```
    GameObject[] cores
    GameObject closest_core = null;

    cores = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("bldg_core");
    if (cores.Length != 1)
        for (int x = 0; x < cores.Length - 1; x++) {
            if (distanceToPlayer (cores [x + 1]) < distanceToPlayer(closest_core))
                closest_core = cores [x+1];
        }
```

Comment: Depending on what `distanceToPlayer` returns when the argument is `null`, you might need to add a null check to the condition: `if (closest_core == null || ... )`